# How to compose Gmail redirection URL?

Tags: php, email, gmail, imap

I would like discuss a scenario on this platform.I am reading my Gmail mailbox using a PHP-IMAP script, what this script output is all recent email received(display output over browser).But when I clicked on link of html content it gets redirected directly to destination page.When same link is clicked by logging in the mailbox then over browser below link comes:

```
https://www.google.com/url?hl=en&q=your destination url&&source=gmail&ust=1527574500284000&usg=AFQjCNHq5hhWc_N4GCabYZm0G2pMkfEIEA
```

I understand this is done by gmail to manage redirection and tracking. Below are my queries to understand it better:
1. By knowing destination is it possible to re-create URL saved by gmail in tag data-saferedirecturl.
2. What could be achieved by gmail in doing so.